# Pandas threshold data sequence based on the length of pattern

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I have this data frame

```
    A
0   -2
1   0
2   2
3   2
4   0
5   0
6   0
7   0
8   0
9   0
10  0
11  0
12  2
13  2
14  2
15  2
16  2
17  3
18  2
19  0
20  2
21  2
22  2
```

and it's plot is like this

[image]

I want to threshold data based on the length of the sequence for the above example flattening the B part because it's length is less than 3 like below

[image]

Comment: The solution to this will require sequential processing of the data, which will kill your speed. is that acceptable to you?

Comment: Why do you keep that negative bit in the beginning, its size is 1.

Comment: @anand_v.singh any solution is acceptable :)

Comment: @ALollz y=0 is my baseline and any data above that should be checked for thresholding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alternative solution without for loop (using df from @anand_v.singh's answer):

1. mask of records above baseline (y=0):

```
    positive_mask = df>0
```

2. label groups of sequenced positive values:

```
    sequence_groups = positive_mask.astype(int).diff(1).fillna(0).abs().cumsum().squeeze()
```

3. check the size of each sequence group

```
    sequence_size = positive_mask.groupby(sequence_groups).transform(len)
```

4. putting it all together (just for see the dataframe and steps results side by side)

```
    df_extended = pd.concat([df, positive_mask, sequence_groups, sequence_size], axis=1)
    df_extended.columns = ['value', 'is_positive', 'sequence_group', 'sequence_size']
    df_extended

        value  is_positive  sequence_group  sequence_size
    0      -2        False             0.0              2
    1       0        False             0.0              2
    2       2         True             1.0              2
    3       2         True             1.0              2
    4       0        False             2.0              8
    5       0        False             2.0              8
    6       0        False             2.0              8
    7       0        False             2.0              8
    8       0        False             2.0              8
    9       0        False             2.0              8
    10      0        False             2.0              8
    11      0        False             2.0              8
    12      2         True             3.0              7
    13      2         True             3.0              7
    14      2         True             3.0              7
    15      2         True             3.0              7
    16      2         True             3.0              7
    17      3         True             3.0              7
    18      2         True             3.0              7
    19      0        False             4.0              1
    20      2         True             5.0              3
    21      2         True             5.0              3
    22      2         True             5.0              3
    23      0        False             6.0              1
    24      3         True             7.0              2
    25      3         True             7.0              2
    26      0        False             8.0              1
```

5. flat all values that are positive and the sequence size is lower than 3:

```
    flat_mask = (df_extended.sequence_size < 3) & (df_extended.is_positive)
    df_extended.loc[flat_mask, 'value'] = 0
```

6. plot

```
    df_extended.value.plot()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok so first let's create out dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame([-2,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,3,2,0,2,2,2,0,3,3,0])
df.columns = ['A']
df
```

I have added two 3's and a 4 at the end just for sanity check, this gives us

```
    A
0   -2
1   0
2   2
3   2
4   0
5   0
6   0
7   0
8   0
9   0
10  0
11  0
12  2
13  2
14  2
15  2
16  2
17  3
18  2
19  0
20  2
21  2
22  2
23  0
24  3
25  3
26  0
```

Now we have to see which elements have to be turned to zero for that use

```
prev = None
flag = 0
terminationLst = []
for val,i in zip(df['A'],df.index):
  if val == 0 and prev == None: #First time encountering a zero element
    prev = i 
    continue
  if val !=0 and prev != None: #Encountering a non zero element after having seen a zero
    flag = 1
  elif val == 0 and i-prev > 3: Encountering a zero after more than 3 consecutive none zeros
    prev = i
  elif val == 0 and i-prev <=3 and flag ==1: #Encountering a zero after less than 3 consecutive non zeros
    flag = 0
    terminationLst.append([x for x in range(prev+1,i)])
    prev = i
print (terminationLst)
```

which gives us the index of elements we need to turn to zero `[[2, 3], [24, 25], [27]]`

Now we just have to turn them to zero which can be done simply by

```
for elem in terminationLst:
  df['A'].iloc[elem] = 0
```

And now the dataframe becomes

```
    A
0   -2
1   0
2   0
3   0
4   0
5   0
6   0
7   0
8   0
9   0
10  0
11  0
12  2
13  2
14  2
15  2
16  2
17  3
18  2
19  0
20  2
21  2
22  2
23  0
24  0
25  0
26  0
27  0
28  0
```

If you have any issues understanding any specific parts, feel free to comment below.

Comment: I think the OP may actually be looking for peaks that are not wider than 3 units on the x-axis, that is, it may not be just a 0 value all the time. You probably should compare to ```val == df.loc[i, 'A']```

Comment: @kerwei In the question, the peak at C is unchanged in the second graph, it would be easy to incorporate what you propose, but then he also has to say what he wants the peaks to then become.